# How can I prove the following? $|x + x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n| ≥ |x| − (|x_1| + |x_2| + ...+|x_n|)$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Let $x$ be real, and $n$ is natural. How do I get started of proving such thing?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/42969) and don't choose random tags. This has nothing to do with “infinitesimals.”

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Do you mean $$\left|a+b\right|\geq |a|-|b|$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are considering real numbers (this inequality holds for more general cases). If you know the triangle inequality for real numbers $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$ then $$|a| = |a+b-b|\le |a+b|+|b| \Rightarrow |a|-|b| \le |a+b|.$$ Now your result follows by induction.